# Share text intent in html format

Tags: java, android

I want to share a link from my application with any other android application ( Mail, Whatsapp, ...).

The link text is very long, so I preferred to use HTML format to share it.

Here is my code :

```
String linkHtml = "<a href=\"very_long_url\" >link here!</a>";
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(linkHtml, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
} else { 
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(linkHtml));
}
intent.setType("text/plain");
                Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, null);
                context.startActivity(shareIntent);
```

But the result is that "Link here!" is not clickable, and not forward to the original link.

Question: can we share text in HTML format, if yes? how to do that? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why didn't you try with Firebase Deeplinking. Its a better solution to share key value using the links.

Comment: this is new for me, i will try it and let you know

Comment: thank you, i will use bitly its better and easy to use